# Difference between "Build Selection" and "Build Solution" in VS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Curious guy here.

I have noticed there are two buttons/menu alternatives to build:

- Build Solution
- Build [project name] (called "Build Selection" in the build toolbar settings)

What is the difference?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Build Selection* will build the project currently selected in the Solution Explorer. If it depends on other projects, then they will be built too.

*Build Solution* will build all of the projects in the solution (so long as they are marked for build in the solution's configuration).